# Initialising an m x n 2D-Array to 0

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, initialization, parameter-passing

I am trying to initialise a 2d-array to 0 in C of size m x n which are inputs in my function. Here is an example (not interested in the output hence void type):

```
void createArray(int m, int n)
{
    int array[m][n]={0};
}
```

I get the error: "Variable-sized object may not be initialized". I had no luck when I used "const int" instead of "int" also.

This works fine if I don't try to assign 0 to the array:

```
void createArray(int m, int n)
{
    int array[m][n];
}
```

Is there a way around this? It seems inefficient to have to loop over the array setting all values to 0, but maybe this is how C initialises it anyway?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value

Answer (score 1):

> It seems inefficient to have to loop over the array setting all values
> to 0

It won't affect the performance. The initialization loop is transformed into a call to memset zero ( for gcc -O3 compiler flag )

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

reference -
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: I do not get the first line of this. Is it the same as the "you can try"? Also, please be more assertive, i.e. away "try" answers please.

Comment: A loop may be more, less or equally efficient as `memset`. `memset` might have to deal with precautions in case of misalignment, which a plain for loop won't need to do.